# Change Format for contact filed using contact form 7 plugin

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I am using the contact form 7 plugin under wordpress website. I want to say that the form that i have created have some fields. There is a contact phone field where I want the format like this (xxx.xxx.xxxx) opposite to this one (xxxxxxxxxx). Can anyone help to me,if any code and script is needed to done this please give me with suitable code.

Thanks...

Comment: anyone please help me here?

Comment: please share your codes.then only other programmers can help you.

Comment: i have plugin fileds and its shortocdes, can i provide here to you?

Comment: @softphoton321 please edit your question and add your form shortcode.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `Contact Form 7` you can install this form validation plugin
[Jquery Validation For Contact Form 7](https://wordpress.org/plugins/jquery-validation-for-contact-form-7) and then just add any validation you need: https://dnesscarkey.com/jquery-validation/how-to-use

1. Install [Jquery Validation For Contact Form 7](https://wordpress.org/plugins/jquery-validation-for-contact-form-7)
2. It should add new options on Contact Form page:
   [image: Contact Form 7 Options]
3. Use right panel to generate shotcode for phone input. Something like `[text my_phone class:phoneUS]` or `[text* my_phone class:phoneUS]` (if phone is required)

I haven't used wordpress for long time, but according to documentation this should work.

Comment: i don't find a proper solution here please help me out if you any suitable solution thanks.

Comment: please share steps to be followed and then links as reference.